# Alsa sometimes fails to load at laptop startup

Tags: 14.04, sound, lubuntu, startup, alsa

I've Lubuntu 14.04.2 LTS installed on my Toshiba L30-10T laptop. Sometimes, Alsa fails to load at laptop startup : I've no sound on my computer and I've to type `sudo alsa force-reload` one or two times to get sound back.

I also suspect this sound problem to cause computer freeze during use or when shutting down it.

RealTek module (snd_hda_codec_realtek) seems not to be well started in both dmesg / alsa-info file when issue occurs.

Does anyone solve similar issue ?

Here are some files :

alsa-info when alsa fails at startup :

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=f0a6e32721ec42dc3bdbfb312d8f0c36bb33fc80

dmesg when alsa fails at startup :

```
[    5.223878]  excluding 0xf0300000-0xf03fffff
[    5.244508] ath5k 0000:09:04.0: registered as 'phy0'
[    5.754234] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[    5.754244] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[    5.754248] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    5.754251] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    5.754254] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    5.754257] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    5.754260] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    5.761394] hda-intel 0000:00:14.2: Using LPIB position fix
[    5.761514] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:14.2: irq 40 for MSI/MSI-X
[    5.776486] hda-intel 0000:00:14.2: Enable sync_write for stable communication
[    5.985298] init: failsafe main process (519) killed by TERM signal
[    6.430700] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x64
[    6.430707] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    6.430712] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    6.430714] ath: Regpair used: 0x64
[    6.444811] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[    6.445668] ath5k: phy0: Atheros AR2413 chip found (MAC: 0x78, PHY: 0x45)
```

alsa-info when alsa does not fails at startup (snd_hda_codec_realtek apears in module list) :

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=b8636d7b4d18375263322c2905496ea15260fd0e

dmesg when alsa does not fails at startup (realtek apears) :

```
[    4.735076]  excluding 0xf0300000-0xf03fffff
[    4.823552] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    4.857510] ath5k 0000:09:04.0: registered as 'phy0'
[    5.038531] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[    5.704731] init: failsafe main process (564) killed by TERM signal
[    5.736733] hda-intel 0000:00:14.2: Using LPIB position fix
[    5.737024] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:14.2: irq 40 for MSI/MSI-X
[    5.748862] hda-intel 0000:00:14.2: Enable sync_write for stable communication
[    5.786351] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[    5.786360] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[    5.786370] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    5.786373] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    5.786376] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    5.786379] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    5.786382] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    6.146764] autoconfig: line_outs=1 (0x15/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[    6.146772]    speaker_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    6.146775]    hp_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    6.146777]    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    6.146779]    inputs:
[    6.146782]      Mic=0x18
[    6.146785] realtek: Enabling init ASM_ID=0x820d CODEC_ID=10ec0862
[    6.156422] autoconfig: line_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[    6.156431]    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    6.156433]    hp_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    6.156436]    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    6.156438]    inputs:
[    6.162612] input: HDA ATI SB Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input10
[    6.162816] input: HDA ATI SB Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input9
[    6.263610] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x64
[    6.263617] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    6.263622] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    6.263624] ath: Regpair used: 0x64
[    6.277414] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[    6.278323] ath5k: phy0: Atheros AR2413 chip found (MAC: 0x78, PHY: 0x45)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally switch to Debian 8 with XFCE and solve my sound issue with my Toshiba L30-10T laptop.

Freeze still occurs sometimes with Debian but less frequently. Disabling wifi network interface fix computer freeze.

I didn't find the root cause of my sound issue with Lubuntu.